# продлить вектор до оси

Tags: unity3d

Есть камера. У неё есть вектор оси Х в глобальной позиции (transform.forward).
Как продлить этот "луч" пока Y не будет 0 ?

Сейчас сделал через цикл, прибавляю в transform.position + transform.forward, пока Y не станет 0. 
Как иначе так и не придумал. нашел примерное названии задачи как "нахождение следа прямой".

То есть нужна точка пересечения с осью в направлении transform.forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

векторное уравнение прямой

```
 ->  ->     ->
 r = r0 + t*u
```

где r0 - координаты камеры (x,y,z), u - направляющий вектор (camera.transform.forward в мировой системе отсчета).

исходя из того что r.y = 0 находим t :

```
 0 = r0.y + t*u.y -> t = -(r0.y/u.y)
```

далее находим x и z :

```
 r.x = r0.x + t*u.x
 r.z = r0.z + t*u.z
```

P.S. Это не вектор продлить до оси, а найти точку пересечения прямой (выше) и плоскости (Y=0) :-) Unity не любит когда так "вольно" трактуют понятия, имейте в виду :-)

АЛСО, возьмите [модуль Math3D](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions) - там есть все базовые ф-ции, в том числе и пересечение прямой с плоскостью.

Comment: вольность никто не любит) но правильнее просто не могу сейчас выразиться, надо эту тему всю подтягивать.
главное суть задачи получилось донести, спасибо за ответ! 
взял Math3d, все получилось.